# UnsupportedOperationException when adding to a map in kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin, exception, crash

I have a crash, that only happened once in my app, due to an UnsupportedOperationException when I try to add an item to a map. For the stacktrace it seems that an AbstractMap is instantiated instead of a MutableMap. The code is in kotlin:

```
val productMap: MutableMap<ProductModel, Int> =
            binding.myView.getProductMap() as? MutableMap<ProductModel, Int>
                ?: mutableMapOf()

            presenter.getProduct()?.let {
                productMap.put(it, 0)
            }
```

Could it be that kotlin/java did something weird behind curtains or is there anything I am missing?

The stacktrace:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
       at java.util.AbstractMap.put(AbstractMap.java:218)
       at com.package.MyView.method2(MyView.java:108)
       at com.package.MyParentView.method1(MyParentView.java:1278)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue here is that **[`MutableMap`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/-mutable-map/) is a [mapped type](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/java-interop.html#mapped-types)**: the Kotlin compiler knows about the difference between `Map` and `MutableMap`, but they both compile down to [`java.util.Map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) in the Java<sup>*</sup> bytecode. That's because the underlying Java classes don't distinguish mutable from immutable collections; they use the same interface for both, and immutable implementations simply throw `UnsupportedOperationException`.

So in this case, **the `as?` safe cast doesn't do what you want**: it's effectively checking only whether the object is a `Map`, not whether it's mutable. (I don't know Android, but if `getProductMap()` is defined to return a `Map`, then that boils down to a simple null check.)

There are several approaches to fixing this, depending on your needs, e.g.:

- If you happen to know the concrete, mutable type you expect (such as `ArrayList`), then you could cast to that. Since `ArrayList`s are always mutable, the `put()` should then be safe; but it would do nothing any other type of map was provided.
- You could trap the `UnsupportedOperationException` in a `try`…`catch` block. This would avoid the error, but do nothing if an immutable map was provided.
- You could create a mutable map from the given map, using `toMutableMap()`. This would always update the map — but it might be a private map not used by the view.

---

<sup>(* The stack trace shows that this question is about Kotlin/JVM.  You might get different results on other platforms.)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is what happens here, but we should not really cast read-only types to mutable like this. If the return type of `getProductMap()` is `Map`, not `MutableMap` then this is probably for a reason and we should not try to use it as it is mutable.

For example, [buildList(): List](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/build-list.html) utility actually returns a list that implements `MutableList`, but is in fact read-only and throws exceptions when we try to modify it. Similarly, collections returned from utils like [Collections.unmodifiableMap()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableMap(java.util.Map)) can be cast to mutable.

I think what you really need to do here is to create a mutable copy of the data in the map:

```kotlin
binding.myView.getProductMap().toMutableMap()
```

Or, if `getProductMap()` returns nullable:

```kotlin
binding.myView.getProductMap()?.toMutableMap() ?: mutableMapOf()
```

As a side note, your code seems strange to me. It uses the contents of the source map if it is mutable, but it ignores its contents if it is not.